# List view adapter onclick method use in oncreate

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My main activity

```
   public void removefunction(){
    List<CartItem> cartItems = getCartItems(cart);
    cart.remove(cartItems.get(position).getProduct());
    cartItems.remove(position);
    cartItemAdapter.updateCartItems(getCartItems(cart));
    cartItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    tvTotalPrice.setText(Constant.CURRENCY+String.valueOf(cart.getTotalPrice().setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)));
}
```

Adapter code

```
 btnremove= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnrem);

    btnremove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ((ShoppingCartActivity) context).removefunction();


        }
    });
```

Cause null pointer exception in tvTotalPrice.setText

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.android.tonyvu.sc.demo, PID: 7601
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference at
>   com.android.tonyvu.sc.demo.ShoppingCartActivity.removefunction(ShoppingCartActivity.java:263)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.tonyvu.sc.demo.adapter.CartItemAdapter$1.onClick(CartItemAdapter.java:98)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ButtonClick event is alright, as your method triggers the setText method. The problem is that your tvTotalPrice-Textview is not set (or wrong set), which is the reason why it is null. That's why you get the NullPointerException.

Comment: final TextView tvTotalPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTotalPrice);
        tvTotalPrice.setText(Constant.CURRENCY+ String.valueOf(cart.getTotalPrice().setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)));

Comment: Is the TextView in the MainActivity or an item in the ListView?

Comment: sir its done thnx alot for ur help

Comment: You're welcome :) Please mark the answer as correct